# TFS 2017 Active Directory groups use in GroupsandPermissions.xml

Tags: xml, templates, tfs

My company uses active directory groups specific to TFS where there are a few groups created for each project. In the GroupsandPermissions.xml project definition, we would like to set a template to create the like-TFS group, and then include as its members the AD group. In the process template, we don't want to edit the GroupsAndPermissions.xml template for each new group.

For example, for Team Project named "Project1" we would like to create a group named "Dev Leads", and have defined the AD group already as TFS-Project1-DevLead.

In the template, the creation looks something like:

```
...
<group name="Dev Leads" isTeam="true" description="This is my team of DevLeads for the project">
  <permissions>
    <permission name="GENERIC_READ" class="PROJECT" allow="true" />
  </permissions>
  <members>
    <member name="DOMAIN\TFS-{Project_name_variable}-DevLead" />
  </members>
</group>
```

I would like to be able to use the variable "{Project_name_variable}" where it comes from the name of the project being created.

I tried using one of the macro names (TFS-[$$PROJECTNAME$$]-DevLead) with disastrous results (i.e., error for unsupported characters).

Can this be done in the process templates?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, this is not support. You could take a look at below **Description and syntax** of `member` Element

> Required child element of members. Specifies **the name of a group**
>   that you are adding as a member of another group. You can create
>   groups and automatically populate them with TFS default groups,
>   previously defined project groups, and groups and users in Active
>   Directory.
>
> ```
> <member name="MemberName" >
> </member>
> ```

Generally  speaking you could either add a group name or default groups. For information about how to specify default groups, see [Group macros and default groups.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/work/customize/reference/process-templates/configure-initial-groups-teams-members-permissions#group-macros-and-default-groups)

[image]

You could only use above macros, `"DOMAIN\TFS-{Project_name_variable}-DevLead"` is not support. Unless you use a hard-code AD group with specific project name such as  `"DOMAIN\TFS-Project1-DevLead"`

Comment: Thanks for verification. I was trying to avoid having to hardocde the AD group name since the project name is used as part of the AD group, and was looking for some type of variable subsitution.